# Android App to translate conversations offline

Tags: android, offline, translation

Searching for an (Android) App that translates conversations, i.e. does Speech-To-Text, translates and then does Text-To-Speech.
Apps like the popular Google Translate app call this "conversation mode". However, Google translate, Bing translate, Yandex translate, and others with the conversation-mode feature do not support it being offline.
And offline apps, e.g. DeepL, don't have a conversation mode.

Does anyone know any app which can do conversation mode during offline phases? (can be paid)